# Can't delete bookmarks or the folder that contains it (Firefox 55)

Tags: firefox, bookmarks

I have two bookmarks in a folder in Firefox (not sure how they were made), both with a location of **http:///**  They're the only two things in that folder.

If I right-click > Delete, nothing happens.  If I right-click > Delete on the folder they're in, nothing happens.

I am able to move the folder around to other locations, but I'm not able to move the "bookmarks" out of that folder.

How can I delete these?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried going into the library and deleting/moving from there?  Ctrl-Shift-B

That could work better.

Comment: Yep, same result. The delete option is there, but it has no effect.

Comment: What about using the star icon, expanding, and deleting from there via using the "Remove Bookmark" button?

Comment: You could also try starting firefox in safe mode to see if the problem persists... https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/troubleshoot-firefox-issues-using-safe-mode